# Does the number of functions in my PHP class affect performance?

Tags: php, performance, class

I'm working on a class in PHP which is now over 4800+ lines long (around 202KB currently) - it contains a large collection of functions. It's *almost* a framework but not generic (or advanced) enough to be worthy of the term.

There is a `__construct()` function which connects to a database and runs one select query, and no public functions.

I simply include the file in the pages I need to use it on, and call it like so:

`<?php $myFramework = new MyFramework(); ?>`

Here's my question - does the amount of functions in my class have any impact on performance over and above whatever impact the `__construct()` function has when it runs?

Does including a 202KB file slow down my web app in any way, such that it might be advisable to split my functions into smaller files?

Comment: You haven't thought about separating the concerns? It is good practice to keep a high cohesion in OOP - it makes your code flexible and reusable. Let your classes do one thing and do it well. Then create composite classes for the bigger picture.

Comment: Chances are, performance is not your biggest problem - the design of your code is. One monstrous class that "does everything" is a sign of poor design. Just benchmark/test your code if you are worried about the time it takes to execute.

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing that people (especially newbies) should *not worry about*! I can hear it already... "*I want to add more functions to this class but I heard it's bad for performance*" Worry more about writing good code, and separation of concerns.

Comment: @WesleyMurch (and clarence) point taken about code design, there is definitely some code I could put into seperate classes that would improve on that and I probably will. However I don't think it's relevant what newbies might think about performance and classes - I'm not asking because I've heard a rumour, I'm asking because I want to know the answer, and this site is here precisely to answer this kind of question.

Comment: @jammypeach: Your question has almost no significance to the real world, and we are not here to benchmark your code. The answer is "it depends". This is a curiosity at best, not the type of thing you should be concerned with while writing code, and impossible to answer in a general way.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I didn't know if the question had any significance until I knew the answer which I can only get by asking. I didn't ask anybody to benchmark my code, if you are in any doubt I suggest you re-read the question. Wouldn't it be nice if I just knew it already...

Comment: @jammypeach: Despite my brusque replies, I am actually trying to help you realize the answer to your question. The answer is "it depends" and "it doesn't matter". The reason you split things into different files is not performance, but organization and separation of concerns, among (many, many) other reasons.

Comment: @WesleyMurch no worries, I do take the point about design and it's definitely something to improve on. I really just wanted to know if I was setting myself up for a clusterf**k in a couple of months time, was starting to think this class is getting pretty big. turns out the answer was yes but just not the way I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only in you case, but not generally:**

If talk about speed, splitting your functions into smaller files will increase count of includes and slow your application down much greater.
As you say, your methods **are logically dealed**, so you may **keep your code as it is**.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't especially *need* them all in the same class, it's basically my database interaction wrapper. all the functions do inserts or deletes or selects, it could be split into smaller classes but I haven't seen any particular advantage in doing that, aside from the code perhaps being a bit more readable.

Comment: +1 If anything splitting the functions out would be a performance hit (unless they arent all needed at a given time, then you might get a slight available memory bump). But the more importan question is whay do you have a class thats 4800 lines long? Most likely some of them **should** be split to separate classes and thus files.

Comment: Dont split them, better write detailed comments for each method, and format the code strictly. That will be better.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. Think lazy-loading.

Comment: As @WesleyMurch said, I'd go to split + lazy loading.

Comment: I shudder thinking about how an inexperienced PHP coder will interpret this answer. "*I heard more files are bad for performance...*"

Comment: @WesleyMurch I did not say "I heard more files are bad for performance..."

Comment: @BogdanBurim: No I know, I'm saying that newbies are very impressionable and without some kind of disclaimer, your answer could easily be misinterpreted. You're suggesting that the OP *not* split his code into different files because of possible performance implications, that is poor advice.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Oh sorry I just wanted to share my opinion, and will modify my answer to prevent confusing someone.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no way to tell...**

May sound a bit vague but it's so generic the only way you can be sure is to measure it.

Then again, if you are worried about performance you'll probably be implementing an opcode cache like **[APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/apc)**. As soon as you do that the class is cached and parsing all the code will be irrelevant.

As a rule of thumb DB queries are almost always the first to be optimized and the bottleneck but, when in doubt, measure.

Comment: fair enough - I know it's a vague question too but it's a little too big to post the code :) My server is running ACP as it happens, so it's good to know that will be cached either way.

Comment: Just a comment. There is way to tell) I used to measure the difference in one project. But, of course, without APC. That was open-source application so we could not rely on APC. It mught be used without APC.

Comment: @BogdanBurim, of course there is a way to tell! ;) I meant that there is no way to tell *without testing* as any scenario could be faster in the OP's relative case.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much depends on the fact if every request requires all that code. If not, you are loading way more data per request then necessary.

Basically: if all the code is necessary for each request, putting it all in one file is the fastest. If it is not, splitting it up is much faster.